# Static countdown with javascript/php, how?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
var austDay = new Date("May 18, 2012 00:00:00");
            $('#countdown').countdown({until: austDay});
```

Is what I got. I wish to make this static, which I mean by it shows the same countdown in all timezones. So no matter if you change your timezone or your date on your pc, it should not affect the countdown and it should still be e.g 8 hours left.

Maybe this is not possible because Javascript is Client side?

What can I do? I really want it to live countdown and not so you need to refresh. Maybe I can use some help from PHP?

The countdown should be the same for example 4 hours left, it should also display that in new york and asia..

Comment: var austDay = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 4, 18));

Comment: GGG Write as an answer! Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP to pass the server time to the client like so.

```
var time = new Date(<?php echo time()*1000; ?>);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var austDay = new Date("May 18, 2012 00:00:00");
```

This creates a date object with the date and time shown, in the user's *local timezone*. To create a UTC date, you can do something like this instead:

```
var austDay = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 4, 18));
```

...where 4 is the *zero-based* month number (2012 and 18 are the year and day, obviously).

If you need to *display* the date afterwards, use the "UTC" functions instead of their non-UTC counterparts, for example:

```
console.log(austDay.toUTCString()) // "Fri, 18 May 2012 00:00:00 GMT"
```

---

Another problem is that users could change their clocks. To give them something like "8 hours left" and be absolutely sure, you'd have to compare the server time to the client's time and set the date based on that.

For example, if the server knows that the thing happens at noon tomorrow, and it's 9:00 at night, then the countdown ends in 15 hours. You can tell the client how much time is left until the countdown is ready instead of passing them an absolute time.

```
var austDay = new Date();
var hoursLeft = <?php echo $something ?>;

austDay.addHours(hoursLeft);
```

You'd probably want to do it in seconds or smaller instead of hours, I used hours here for simplicity.